# Как ускорить получение и обрезание Bitmap из drawable?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

Проблема - Ощутимая задержка при получении и обрезании `Bitmap` из `drawable`.

```
Bitmap bt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
bt = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bt, width, height, true);
```

Как можно оптимизировать/ускорить получение обрезанного `Bitmap`?

Comment: Вынести в поток, дабы плавно без задержек интерфейс откликался

Comment: @VAandrJ Спасибо за совет,  но мне такой способ не подойдет.

Comment: @Igor, только такой способ существует. Если он вам не подходит, значит ваше приложение построено неправильно, и нужно не искать другой способ (читай *костыль*), а переделать приложение таким образом, чтобы такой способ подходил.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переписать так:

```
Bitmap oldBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oldBitmap, width, height, true);
oldBitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: Переписал не помогло .BitmapFactory.decodeResource  - в 4 раза дольше, чем Bitmap.createScaledBitmap.

Comment: а большого разрешения картинка?

Comment: Да.и размер размер 1080x1920,